# convert base64String into base64Binary java

Tags: java, base64

I need to send base64Binary into SOAP service. I have this method in class, which create base64String:

```
public String encode(final String text) {
    byte[] msgBytes = text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF-8);
    String base64String = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(messageBytes);
    return base64String;
}
```

How can I convert base64String into base64Binary with bytes into base64String?

Comment: With Java 8 you can stop using `DatatypeConverter` and instead use [`Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html). `DatatypeCoverter` is intended for XML Base64 and has known issues when used in the general case.

Comment: What, in your view, is the diffenrence between `base64String` and `base64Binary`?

Answer (score 0):

[DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseBase64Binary(java.lang.String)) can be used to decode a Base64 encoded `String`:

```
byte[] msgBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64String);
```

If you want to convert the `byte[]` to a `String`, you can proceed like:

```
String text = new String(msgBytes , "UTF-8");
```

Comment: this method return me array of bytes

Comment: @Giymose what did you expect?? A Base64 encoded `String` is _exactly that_ - an array of bytes.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I want to save base64String into byte array with bytes, which contains into string. Example: String - dGVzdA==  Array - dGVzdA==

Comment: @Giymose so you want a `String` from `byte[]` or something else?  some `string.getBytes()` ?

Comment: @fantaghirocco I want to put base64String into byte[]. If I use string.getBytes() it give me string bytes, not which content into string

Comment: @Giymose my answer **is** the decoded string into bytes[]. Sorry but I don't get what you want :-s